# Change in reputation noticed 20 FEB 2011 - 22 FEB 2011

Tags: support, reputation

About 2 days ago, I noticed my rep was 1897 points.

Today it's even lower than yesterday at 1642.

Going thru the graph in my profile, however shows no indication that my rep ever touched the 1800 mark.

Is anyone else noticing a problem with the rep points or is it just me?

I haven't noticed any of my answers being downvoted etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably had a reputation re-calc. The number on your profile doesn't change immediately when a question or answer (where you had upvotes/downvotes) is deleted.

I do know that a number of old, closed, off-topic questions were deleted recently.

Comment: I didn't know the deletion of a question affected positive rep.  Good to know.

Comment: And it's happened again. From around 1912 or so, I'm down to 1702. This certainly rates as "odd behaviour" in my book.

Comment: Another possibility: vote fraud. The system does check for unusual voting patterns, like a lot of up or down votes by one person for another in a short amount of time. When it sees those sorts of patterns it rolls back the votes.

Comment: Note that there's nothing you can do about that @Sparx, so it's not to punish you, rather to prevent users from fraudulently upvoting every answer from a single user

Answer (score 1):

They recently did a site-wide rep recalc.    See the discussion at [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc).